# adding a timestamp filter to a range

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, timestamp, accumulo

I am already able to create a scan with a Range.exact(row, cf) and to read a table with it. But I want now to add a timestamp filter to it so I can filter for example "showing only rows that was created after ...".
I know there is a way to add a long to Range.exact, but that doesn't fit my case since I don't want an exact date.
I read about the TimestampFilter class, but it seems that it only filters with timestamps.
How can I create a Range that scan Rows, cf AND Timestamps ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a range and a timestamp filter to the scanner by using both method calls, [`Scanner.setRange(...)`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.8.1/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Scanner.html#setRange(org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Range)) and [`Scanner.addScanIterator(...)`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.8.1/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/ScannerBase.html#addScanIterator(org.apache.accumulo.core.client.IteratorSetting)), before iterating over the entries in the scanner.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/4bbf52ee709aefebc47adc54fea908d1b2fe576c/gora-accumulo/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/accumulo/store/AccumuloStore.java#L852-L858) of adding a timestamp filter to a scanner.